# What are the ways to deploy node js in Aws?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-ecs

I need to develop API using node js and deploy them in Aws. What are the ways I could deploy node.js in AWS with server and serverless ?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways you can deploy solutions that uses Node JS to the AWS Cloud. You can deploy an application to Elastic Beanstalk. You can find a number of online tutorials that shows you how to perform this task.

You can also create Lambda solutions that uses Node JS.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-nodejs.html

Talking it a step further, you can build serverless workflows that addresses business requirements by using AWS Step Functions. Each workflow step can be implemented as a Lambda function created with Node JS.

https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/create-a-serverless-workflow-step-functions-lambda/